# Count number of occurances using LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I need to count number of occurences of the same strings in txt file.

What I have come up with is

```
public class CountWords {
public File file;
public Scanner scan = null;
public LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> list = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public CountWords(String txt) {
    file = new File(txt);
}

public void textEdit() {

    try {
        scan = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("----");
    }

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        if(!list.containsKey(line))
            list.put(scan.next(),1);
        else {
            list.put(line,list.get(line)+1);
        }
    }
    scan.close();
}
public List<String> getResult(){
    textEdit();
    return list;
}
```

the class Main shouldn't be changed in any way (that is the requirement)
and the output should be in the same order as input (that's why LinkedHashMap is used)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String fname = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/textforwords.txt";
        CountWords cw = new CountWords(fname);
        List<String> result = cw.getResult();
        for (String wordRes : result) {
            System.out.println(wordRes);
        }
    }
}
```

I missed something that I can't figure out.

Comment: Does this compile?  getResult is declared to return a List but you are returning a LinkedHashMap.

Comment: @JimmyJames no
and this is the place where I have confused
I need to connect this two things somehow, because the requirement were "not to change Main" and "use LinkedHashMap"

Comment: What kind of strings should the list returned by `getResult()` contain? Do you got a specification for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a count of strings or lines?

If you need to count of strings, try this:

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    String line = scan.next();
    if(!list.containsKey(line))
        list.put(line,1);
    else {
        list.put(line,list.get(line)+1);
    }
}
```

And `getResult` you can modify like this:

```
public List<String> getResult(){
    textEdit();

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : list.entrySet()){
        result.add(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    }
    return result;
}
```

P.S. I can not add a comment